# BFS Traversal for a Tree

Tags: java, tree, breadth-first-search

Is it possible to traverse a tree level order not using queue or recursion. The run complexity can be high but constant space complexity i.e. using a loop?

Comment: Constant space complexity isn't possible for _any_ mechanism of traversing a tree, but it sounds like you're looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search .

Comment: Unless the problem has some particular special circumstances, your interviewer was wrong.

Comment: A possible solution which we discussed was follows:

a) Create a large bit map, with each bit representing the path from root node to node which is to be traversed. For e.g. if we are traversing RLRLR node, then the 5 bit from left could be set etc. 

b) There is a loop which, picks bits from this bitmap and passes it to another function, which decodes the bit to find the node to be reached.

c) Using the code obtained from bitmap, do subsequent LRLR etc ...the final trick to get the programming code in java from this coded bit .. which confuses me a lot ..

Comment: Your "large bit map" is not going to be constant size.  I'm not sure I understand the encoding mechanism you're describing, but it'll either be O(log n) or O(n) sized.

Comment: yes, true ... that is the best I could get ... at the same time could not get to last part where this bit map could be translated to a tree .. .one solution which I could formulate was to have an extra pointer from left to right node or vice-versa so as tree can be traversed in a loop ... Ah! overly complicated for such trivial problem ..if space is a big issue may as well have more than one tree :)